# How to print entries from an array in order

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, while-loop

I want to populate an array with 7 integers from a console entry, and then print each integer from the array in order;

If my array is `[5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 6, 8]`;

I want to then print;

```
Entry 1 - 5
Entry 2 - 3
Entry 3 - 1
Entry 4 - 2
Entry 5 - 2
Entry 6 - 6
Entry 7 - 8
```

I know I can iterate through the array using a while loop, but I don't know how to change the Entry number every time.

Comment: Can you provide your code - meaning what you have tried, and what didn't work? You have tagged your question as `c#`, but the question is largely theoretical.

Comment: you can iterate through an array also with a `for` loop, it can help you in this scenario

Comment: It seems like you want to learn how to code, from scratch.

Comment: Why not simply `foreach(int i in array) Console.WriteLine(i);`

Comment: @TimSchmelter because it doesn't give him the item index in the array.

Comment: @TimSchmelter why is that simply? he wants to print an index too.

Comment: @fredrik: well, he hasn't mentioned that he needs the index. He has just mentioned that he wants to print all entries in order which they do by default. The sample "output" could also just mean that he wants this order

Comment: @Tim he does mention it Entry 1- 5, etc etc

Comment: @TimSchmelter Did you look at the expected output? It's `Entry <index+1> - <value>`... which your example won't do.

Comment: @Blaatz0r: As i've said, it's nowhere mentioned that it must have this format, it could just be the hint that entry 1 must be 5 and entry 2 must be 3 and so on. This question is unclear.

Comment: @TimSchmelter => What not to get from the following text? I want to then print;

Comment: @Blaatz0r: of course it probably means that, but my point is, he hasn't mentioned it somewhere in the question. And until someone doesn't even know how to explain us his requirement, i don't answer it. If OP would tell us that he had tried a `foreach` but it didn't give him the index, then it would be something that we could answer

Comment: @TimSchmelter Logically I have to agree with you. but sometimes a little 'out of the box' goes hand in hand ;)

Comment: Guys, lets not argue over some one asking a handover code :D

Answer (score 4):

That is what for(;;) loop is designed for. The official documentation is pretty clear and straightforward: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for

Comment: It's either that for a combination of `foreach` and LINQ to construct objects which holds the index and value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *get rid of any loops*, and obtain the outcome in *one go*, you can try *Linq* with `string.Join`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

int[] numbers = new int[] { 5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 6, 8 };

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers
  .Select((value, entry) => $"Entry {entry + 1} - {value}")));
```

Outcome:

```
Entry 1 - 5
Entry 2 - 3
Entry 3 - 1
Entry 4 - 2
Entry 5 - 2
Entry 6 - 6
Entry 7 - 8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] array={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

        for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
             Console.Write("Entry "+(i+1)+"- "+array[i]+"\n");
        }


    }
}
```

Here is the working demo of what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int[] arr=new int[]{5,3,1,2,2,6,8};
     for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
          Console.WriteLine("Entry {0} - {1}",i+1,arr[i]);
}
```